# KQL datetime formatting

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a column,`['timestamp']` in Azure Data Explorer. A certain value, x, is assigned to this timestamp.

Data is being streamed in real time and I would like to take the last value of yesterday's data.
However, when I do a substring() or datetime formatting, for some reason, it changes the date from `2022-08-24` to `2022-08-23`.

Code:

```
datasource
| extend ts1 = (datetime_add('day',-1, todatetime(timestamp)))
| extend ts2 = substring(ts1,0,10)
| extend ts3 = format_datetime(todatetime(ts1), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
| project timestamp, ts1,ts2,ts3
| sort by timestamp desc
```

Output:

| timestamp | ts1 | ts2 | ts3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-25 10:56:09.000 | 2022-08-24 10:56:09.000 | 2022-08-24 | 2022-08-24 |
| 2022-08-25 08:56:09.000 | 2022-08-24 08:56:09.000 | 2022-08-24 | 2022-08-24 |
| 2022-08-25 07:26:09.000 | 2022-08-24 07:26:09.000 | 2022-08-23 | 2022-08-23 |
| 2022-08-25 05:56:09.000 | 2022-08-24 05:56:09.000 | 2022-08-23 | 2022-08-23 |

Required output:
ts2 and ts3 to display `2022-08-24` instead of `2022-08-23`

Please review my code and output and help pls.

Comment: Hi David, I've edited my post and uploaded the code as text

Comment: The code doesn't make much sense. What is the data type of `timestamp`? In what time zone do you display the results?

Comment: timestamp is in datetime. Timezone: UTC+8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 2: Solution**

Since all datetime values are stored in UTC and manipulated as UTC, we will use `datetime_utc_to_local()` to convert our timestamps, so that the values we see in our local TZ display, will now be the actual UTC values.
In our case we use the function with `Australia/West`, so 8 hours are being added to the timestamps.

Please note that in the ADX Web Explorer the results (`utc_to_local` column) look strange since the GUI does an additional transformation and adds another 8 hours.
But remember - the UTC values are what counts.

Now that the timestamps are set to the right UTC values, we can use the `startofday()`.
Once again, the GUI adds another 8 hours to the results, and therefore we get `2022-08-25 08:00:00`.

Once you're done with your calculations, you would probably want to use `datetime_local_to_utc()` to convert the results back to UTC.

```
let datasource = datatable (timestamp:datetime)
[
     datetime("2022-08-24 21:56:09.000")
    ,datetime("2022-08-24 23:26:09.000")
    ,datetime("2022-08-25 00:56:09.000")
    ,datetime("2022-08-25 02:56:09.000")
]; 
datasource
| project   local_TZ                = timestamp
           ,utc_to_local            = datetime_utc_to_local(timestamp, "Australia/West")
| extend    utc_to_local_startofday = startofday(utc_to_local)
| extend    utc                     = datetime_local_to_utc(utc_to_local_startofday, "Australia/West")
```

[image: Solution Results]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42QzQrCMBCE74W+w9JTC1VjtKIRD76DICgSYhpBiUbaLSj48Kat2h8ruLddvpnMRCuEWKBITZZIBYtiQbHXCnw8nlWK4nxl9qjyLXCdretAPu+T71FCaY9Me3QMdMiiCSOzPiHEC0oy7CZHjP5DRkDIf56WpE1yNwfXqcq5zgOuiTkpidZCGyk0X22gNQv41H41LSfMUHI0vNA1Be8wvI5UvxeCt8xSTIQ+isHa3vJsD1A3VJc4d6jLuJUkaA6xuFvnavHr0Le+3aKdrPS2esv6P97ryPkEBhk8Kx4CAAA=)

Comment: See addition ("Once you're done with your calculations...")

Answer (score 1):

Two comments regarding the original code:

- Since timestamp is already of `datetime` type, using `todatetime(timestamp)` has no effect.
- While the use of `datetime_add()` is valid, the same result can be simply achieved with arithmetic operators over timespans, e.g. `timestamp - 1d`

Answer (score 0):

We'll do it in two parts :-)

**Part 1: Understanding the issue.**

The ADX [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime) states:

> **"A datetime value in Kusto is always in the UTC time zone"**

That means that **all datetime operations are done in UTC**.
The results are then converted by your client tool, for displaying purposes, to the time zone you chose.

The demonstration below was done in Azure Web Explorer, set to `Australia/West` time zone (UTC+8).

As you can see, while in the local TZ, all timestamps occur at `2022-08-25`, in UTC two of the timestamps occur at `2022-08-25` but the other two occur at `2022-08-24`.
When we retrieve the start of the day (regardless of the exact method), **the operation is applied to the UTC values**, therefore for two of the timestamps the start of day is `2022-08-25 00:00:00` and for the other two, it is `2022-08-24 00:00:00`.
Only then the result is being converted to the client tool TZ, by adding 8 hours to the results.

```
let datasource = datatable (timestamp:datetime)
[
     datetime("2022-08-24 21:56:09.000")
    ,datetime("2022-08-24 23:26:09.000")
    ,datetime("2022-08-25 00:56:09.000")
    ,datetime("2022-08-25 02:56:09.000")
]; 
datasource
| project   local_TZ            = timestamp
           ,UTC                 = datetime_local_to_utc(timestamp, "Australia/West")
           ,UTC_startofday      = datetime_local_to_utc(startofday(timestamp), "Australia/West")
           ,local_TZ_startofday = startofday(timestamp)
```

[image: issue results]

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42Q3QqCQBCF7wXfYfBKQWvbMsrwInoFIyhCNt3AWFnR8SLo4Vszfwopz90MH%20fMGcERYoaskGUecfBfA7KL4GBikvICWZp5asmrydK1k65BpWZlGpRQ6pCVQxdAZ5679Mh6QggxrJq0h8m5R8eQLhAyzlOR9JM8b0DXunK69oAslzceobIQMmIiDI7Qkw9t5XfLWvY%202MG3/PYFYe2FMiwx6r5mg7EtC8yZSNj0oHbN9T3XUJE5ymvM7r9dO64LsP4mNCX7MT4Mej0BxwEXHwkCAAA=)

Comment: Ahh i see, that explains the 8 hours difference