# How to use KQL to format datetime stamp in 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ'?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-log-analytics-workspace

I receive the error `format_datetime(): failed to parse format string in argument #2` when trying to `format_datetime()` using ISO8601 format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ`.

If I leave the `T` and the `Z` out, it works,

Surely KQL can format datetimestamps in timezone-aware format. I'm just missing it. I read [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/format-datetimefunction) and it appears that `T` and `Z` are not supported formats nor delimiters yet each example in the docs shows the `T` and `Z` present(?).

**Example:**

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where
    AccountName == 'stgtest'
| project
    TimeGenerated = format_datetime(TimeGenerated, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ'), //herein lies the issue
    AccountName,
    RequestBodySize = format_bytes(RequestBodySize)
| sort by TimeGenerated asc
```

If the code is changed to...

```
- `TimeGenerated = format_datetime(TimeGenerated, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')`
```

...it works, but this is not a timezone-aware timestamp (something I prefer to work in to reduce confusion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[datetime_utc_to_local()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datetime-utc-to-local-function)
[Timezones](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/timezone)

I would highly recommend ***not*** doing that.
If possible, you would like to let the time zone & format being dealt on the client side.

All datetime values in KQL are UTC. Always.
Even the result of *datetime_utc_to_local()* is another UTC datetime.
That may lead to (what seems like) unexpected behavior of datetime manipulations ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73482504/kql-datetime-formatting)).

```
StorageBlobLogs
| sample 10
| project TimeGenerated
| extend Asia_Jerusalem     = datetime_utc_to_local(TimeGenerated, "Asia/Jerusalem")
        ,Europe_London      = datetime_utc_to_local(TimeGenerated, "Europe/London")
        ,Japan              = datetime_utc_to_local(TimeGenerated, "Japan")
| extend Asia_Jerusalem_str = format_datetime(Asia_Jerusalem    ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
        ,Europe_London_str  = format_datetime(Europe_London     ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
        ,Japan_str          = format_datetime(Japan             ,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
| project-reorder TimeGenerated, Asia_Jerusalem, Asia_Jerusalem_str, Europe_London, Europe_London_str, Japan, Japan_str
```

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. I want to display the `TimeGenerated` column in the following format: `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ` instead of the default format of `MM/d/yyyy h:mm:ss.ff AM/PM`.

Comment: I just went with ``TimeGenerated = format_datetime(TimeGenerated, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff')`  and forewent the `T` and `Z`. Not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up just using `strcat` to get the exact ISO8601 format I needed when I had to incorporate this format in a URI.

```
strcat(format_datetime(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'T',
       format_datetime(timestamp, 'HH:mm:ss'), 'Z')
```

Not ideal.  I would have preferred something quick like .NETs `ToString("o")`, but this works.